# Reducing the set of constraints in an optimization problem

Tags: inequality, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, constraint-programming

I am a newbie in the domain of optimization. I am trying to solve an optimization problem, which has a set of constraints. Since the number of constraints follows similar pattern I intend to reduce the number of constraints.

My constraints look as below.

$w_1>c_1*w_2$

$w_1>c_2*w_2$

$w_1>c_3*w_2$

$w_1>c_4*w_2$

$w_1>c_5*w_2$

$w_1>c_6*w_2$

$w_1>c_7*w_2$

Here, $c_{i}$ is a constant term and $w_{i}$ is a variable.

This set of constraints have been reduced to two constraints. New set of constraints are

$w_1 > c_{max}*w_2$

$w_1 > c_{min}*w_2$

Here, I assumed the possibilities of positive and negative values of $w_2$ to form above-mentioned constraints. Am I doing it, right?

Secondly,

I am also working with a larger problem, and will have constraints similar to,

$w_1 > c_1*w_2 + c_{11}*w_3$

(having 10000 such constraints)

I tried to follow the same strategy to reduce these set of constraints, and hence got

$w_1 > c_{max}*w_2 + c_{max}*w_3$

$w_1 > c_{max}*w_2 + c_{min}*w_3$

$w_1 > c_{min}*w_2 + c_{max}*w_3$

$w_1 > c_{min}*w_2 + c_{min}*w_3$

Again considering the positive and negative values of $w_{i}$. The above mentioned constraints are not the perfect formulation and its not ideal too as it is evident that the set of constraints increases with n following the relation: $2^{n-1}$, where n is the number of variables. So, for n=70 variables and having 100 such constraints this idea will lead to $2^{70}$ reduced constraints, whereas originally it was only 100.

I am looking an alternative way to reduce them, any suggestion would be highly appreciable.

Comment: A first question would be why you are doing this. If you use a good solver, it will typically have a first presolve stage where redundant constraints are eliminated, and the set of constraints are analyzed along these lines. Sure some trivial pruning (as the bounds) could be reasonable, but don't reinvent the wheel unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand your point but, I am working on a problem which has thousands of such inequalities. To make things reasonable, I am trying to reduce the set of constraints. Please see the second part (my trick does not work there completely) and if you have any suggestions for reduction, then let me know.

Comment: The derivation you've done for your second set of constraints cannot be correct. What you effectively say is that any surface in three dimensions described by a convex piecewise affine function $w_1 \geq  a_i w_2 + b_i w_3$ always can be described by 4 inequalities, which of course is incorrect.

Comment: i.e., you are saying this function http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~mpt/2/downloads/25/mpt_plotPWA1.png can be described using only 4 inequalities...

Comment: Johan sir, Thank you for your detailed answer. As, I am a newbie in the field of Optimization I am not much aware of literatures, which give me some insights to reduce the above-mentioned constraints (for the second part). The second part is just a toy problem actually, I have "n" (in that case n is 3) such variables having 10,000 of constraints. Moreover, I do not want an exact representation of the problem in a compact way (reduced constraints), an approximation is also fine. Will you please suggest me the path or set of literature to move forward?

Comment: To cheaply eliminate redundant constraints, you have to read up on the theory of presolve in linear programs

Comment: Thanks for the response, sir.